# Checked in or checked out

Tags: sharepoint-designer, check-out

Does the check mark indicate that the file is checked out?[image]

Comment: What error do you get everytime? Try refreshing the sharepoint designer. Or just close and open it again and then check in the file, if you have completed doing changes.

Comment: Here's the error message when I try to check in : we can't do that for you because the file is no longer checked out or has been deleted

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the green arrow indicates the file is checked out. This is apparent by your menu options, Check In and Undo check out.

Comment: Here's the error message when I try to check it in: we can't do that for you because the file is no longer checked out or has been deleted

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this issue because of SharePoint designer Cache..
You can clear cache and your problem should be resolved..

Steps to clear SharePoint Cache :

1. Close SPD if it is open
2. Open My Computer and Click the address bar
3. Paste in: **%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache**
4. Delete everything within this location
5. Click the address bar Paste in: **%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache**
6. Delete everything in this location

Source : [How to Clear Your SharePoint Designer 2010/2013 Cache](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/how-to-clear-your-sharepoint-designer-20102013-cache/)